# Qgis2web legend

Tags: web-mapping, style, legend, qgis-2.14, qgis2web

I want to export a vector layer using the Qgis2web plugin.

I styled it with the Leaflet opportunity as the legend with categories is included.

However when I want to export a layer with points sized dependent on some variable the size of the points in the legend are not projected at the same size, see picture.

Is it possible to change the size of the legend or objects in the legend so it's similar to the layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible. However, I have just managed to add this functionality into qgis2web, so expect to see it in a future version:

[image]

UPDATE

I just released qgis2web 2.0.0-beta1 (experimental), which includes this functionality. Please do try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: OK. Thank you for the answer Tom. Will be looking forward to an update :-)

Comment: I'll try to remember to update this answer when the new version is released.